# Setting a unique home page for each store in Magento2

Tags: magento2, multistore, magento-2.0, home

How would I set a a unique home page per store in Magento 2? Is there a way to do this programmatically and in the admin panel as well?

Answer (score 8):

This can be done through the admin, you just need to set the CMS page to only display on the store view you wish instead of all store views.

1. In the admin go to `content > pages`
2. On the right hand side in the 'action' column you should see 'select', click on the relevant select for your CMS page and choose edit (the URL for home pages is `home`)
   [image: Select]
3. Change the store view to the store you want this home page to display for and click save.
   [image: Store scope]
4. Do this for each store/CMS page.

### Additional method

As @JoeConstant commented below:

Additionally, you can change which CMS page is the home page in `Stores->Configuration->General->Web->Default Pages->CMS Home Page` for each website just like in M1.

Comment: Additionally, you can change which CMS page is the home page in Stores->Configuration->General->Web->Default Pages->CMS Home Page for each website just like in M1

Comment: @JoeConstant  You comment helped me. Thanks